# SignalR allows maximum 10 socket connections

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have a simple SignalR Application, created by steps from latest microsoft update https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0. I Am using .net 7 and latests signalr. Also I Have one hub that uses only websockets connection.

Below Program.cs code
`

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            var listenUrl = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ListenUrl");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(listenUrl))
                throw new Exception("Please enter url in appsettings.json -> \"ListenUrl\"");

            builder.WebHost.UseUrls(listenUrl);

            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(_ =>
            {
                _.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 50000;
                _.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 50000;
            });

            builder.Host.UseSerilog(); // <-- Add this line

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionCollector, ConnectionCollector>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWorker, WorkerSpammer>();

            var app = builder.Build();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();
            app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub", options =>
            {
                options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

`
Starting my application via Kestrel from console line and passing to configuration file ip and port for listening.

Also I Have a console application that creates connections to Hub for stress test,

СonsoleConnector.cs
`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GoalConnections; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var connection = await StartConnection(url);
                        Connections.Add(connection);

                        if (i % 20 == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Opened {i} connections");
                        }

                        if ((i + 1) == GoalConnections)
                        {
                            connection.On<Message>("ReceiveMessage", async (message) =>
                            {
                                var now = DateTime.Now;
                                Console.WriteLine($"LastConnection {i} received message with date \"{message.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")}\", at \"{now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")}\". Difference {(now - message.Date).TotalMilliseconds} MS");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Connection {i + 1} - error");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        Errors++;
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
```

`

And when I have started my server and then from another machine started console connector, my console connector could open only 10 connections. Maybe somebody have conjectures why only 10. Server started on kestrel on windows

I tried to run it on IIS , but on iis there is a limit for 10 connections but in this situation u using kestrel, and when I start everything on localhost on the same machine everything works fine, I able to open around 6000 connections, but when its real networks only 10.

Comment: That is a limit of Windows non-server edition. If you want more connections you need to use a Windows Server OS.

Comment: Is I know, it is on Windows Server edition, because on that server already running some websites